# View RPC RMI related code in Network file system

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, rpc, nfs, vfs

I am studying Network File system and there mechanisms, they use RPC to run commands on remote machine (server). I have tried bare RPC assignments, like generating stubs using RPCgen, and running client server code.

I would like to know where in the kernel source can I find the RPC related code for Network File system. At which layer does it calls the RPC generated function, ie at VFS itself or the native filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, kernel does not use rpcgen generated code. You can find NFS/RPC related code at:

nfs client: fs/nfs
   nfs server: fs/nfsd
   rpc code:   net/sunrpc

For client ( this is what you probably looking for) entry point will be fs/nfs/super.c, if you looking at VFS layer or nfs3proc.c/nfs4proc.c, if you want to look at RPC layer.